# Tranistioning back end of Access database to ODBC in order to fix slowness

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I've inherited the task of maintaining a massive Access database stored on a network drive. Users complain that the database is extremely slow. I'm hoping to fix this.

Here is some background:

From a development standpoint, the structure is messy. VBA is littered with unused procedures and modules. It seems that over the years developers have haphazardly slapped on additional features at the request of management. The whole thing is actually composed of a front end Access database and several Access databases that act as the back end where tables are stored. To use the database users open a separate Access database with an autoexecute that copies the front end to the user's local drive and opens the copy. The other developer claims that Access isn't well suited to handle the tasks we are asking it to do. While I agree, I also believe we can do a lot to improve what we got.

Now on to my questions:

Can I make this database significantly faster by consolidating the back end tables into an ODBC database? Does this ODBC database need its own server or can I use the existing share drive this database is currently stored in? How do I create an ODBC database?

I do not have much experience with databases beyond Access and SQL. I do have MS SQL Server Management Studio and TOAD but I've only used them for Querying existing ODBC databases. Any resources I should take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically `ODBC database` is not an actual thing. Most commercial databases have `ODBC drivers`, including Access (which would also make it an `ODBC database`). What you can relatively easily convert Access back-ends to is SQL Server. There is even a (relatively flawed and a pain to set up but functional) migration wizard for that.

Depending on the database you may or may not see much of an improvement but, depending on your database skills, there is huge potential for improvement.

SQL server has a free version and can be hosted on any Windows computer, but having a dedicated server (or at least a server, even if it is not dedicated) has serious advantages.

Most of the above also applies to other database systems you could use like MySQL (also free but I am not aware of a migration tool).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is the migration wizard you are referring to the ODBC Database option under More in the Export section of the External Data tab? I couldn't get this to create anything but a User Data Source which cannot exist on share drives.